# Is there a dynamic DNS update utility packeged for Debian 7 (Wheezy)?

Tags: debian, dns, debian-wheezy, dynamic-dns, noip

[NoIP.com](http://www.noip.com/)'s free dynamic DNS service suggests installing an [unpackaged Linux client](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/) on anything other than Ubuntu. Is there really no Debian package of a client (not necessarily theirs of course) which supports their service?

I'm specifically interested in a package for Debian Wheezy (7.x).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install noip2`?

Comment: @NathanC: `E: Unable to locate package noip2`

Comment: noip2 is still in unstable, see https://packages.debian.org/sid/noip2